GMSK Modulator Large sample Buffer size and high Bandwidth
I found good answers to my queries here Gaussian Pulse shaping filter and suggestion for NCO based GMSK modulator seems to be undersstandable. Thanks to  Dan Boschen
, but when moving ahead to design NCO based GMSK modulator with Gausian filter comming first i am having trouble with concept of pulses since samples/symbol come out to be a big value like considereing AIS case it is like 2 Msps/ 9600 bps= 208.3 ~ 208. SDR operates on 2 Msps. Now considering 256 bit AIS message ( packed unsigned bytes in (0, 1) or unpacked signed bytes (-1 1))  Now 256*208=53248 byte buffe is required for processing.
I thought that mightbe working on low  sampling rate would be beneficial. It is intially seems true as i chose 96k sampling rate and number of samples/symbol reduced to 10 and only 10 x 256=2560 sized buffer is used for processing.
But finally i had to do interpolation to match with the SDR sampling rate (2 Msps) so all this benefit vanished as any how i need to send more samples (same 53248) to SDR and most SDR dont accept this much bytes and samples are sent in more than one iteration. I think i have not understood completely or missed something. I dont want to use gnuradio or other libraries, would like to understand and imlpement uing C or C++.
This is what i have been doing
 // Parameters for Gaussian filtering and GMSK modulation
    double bt = 0.4;  // Bandwidth-time product for AIS standard
    int samples_per_bit = (int)(2000000 / 9600);  // Sample rate / data rate
    int span = 4;  // Span of the filter in bit durations
    double carrier_frequency = 0.0;  // Carrier frequency in Hz (For Zero IF) 
    double sampling_rate = 2000000;  // Sampling rate in Hz

    // Generate Gaussian filter
    int filter_length = samples_per_bit * span;
    double* gaussian_filter = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * filter_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < filter_length; i++) {
        gaussian_filter[i] = exp(-pow((i - filter_length / 2.0) / (samples_per_bit * bt), 2) / 2) / sqrt(2 * M_PI * pow(bt, 2));
    }
    double filter_sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < filter_length; i++) {
        filter_sum += gaussian_filter[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < filter_length; i++) {
        gaussian_filter[i] /= filter_sum;  // Normalize filter
    }

    // Create pulses from NRZI data
    int pulse_length = strlen(ais_message) * samples_per_bit;
    double* pulses = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * pulse_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(ais_message); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < samples_per_bit; j++) {
            pulses[i * samples_per_bit + j] = nrzi_data_bipolar[i];
        }
    }

    // Apply Gaussian filter to the pulses
    double* filtered_signal = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * pulse_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < pulse_length; i++) {
        filtered_signal[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < filter_length; j++) {
            if (i - j >= 0 && i - j < pulse_length) {
                filtered_signal[i] += pulses[i - j] * gaussian_filter[j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Phase Integration
    double* phase_integral = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * pulse_length);
    phase_integral[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < pulse_length; i++) {
        phase_integral[i] = phase_integral[i - 1] + filtered_signal[i - 1] * 2 * M_PI * 0.5 / samples_per_bit;  // Modulation index 0.5
    }

    // NCO-based GMSK Modulation
    double* gmsk_waveform_i = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * pulse_length);
    double* gmsk_waveform_q = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * pulse_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < pulse_length; i++) {
        double phase = 2 * M_PI * carrier_frequency / sampling_rate * i + phase_integral[i];
        gmsk_waveform_i[i] = cos(phase);
        gmsk_waveform_q[i] = sin(phase);
    }

    // Convert double-precision IQ samples to CS16 format
    int16_t* iq_samples_cs16 = (int16_t*)malloc(sizeof(int16_t) * 2 * pulse_length);
    double max_val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < pulse_length; i++) {
        if (fabs(gmsk_waveform_i[i]) > max_val) max_val = fabs(gmsk_waveform_i[i]);
        if (fabs(gmsk_waveform_q[i]) > max_val) max_val = fabs(gmsk_waveform_q[i]);
    }
    double scale = 32767.0 / max_val;
    for (int i = 0; i < pulse_length; i++) {
        iq_samples_cs16[2 * i] = (int16_t)(gmsk_waveform_i[i] * scale);
        iq_samples_cs16[2 * i + 1] = (int16_t)(gmsk_waveform_q[i] * scale);
    }

    // Output waveform to file or SDR
    FILE* file = fopen("gmsk_waveform_iq_cs16.bin", "wb");
    if (file) {
        fwrite(iq_samples_cs16, sizeof(int16_t), 2 * pulse_length, file);
        fclose(file);
    }

So can anyone help me on this.
The other issue is even if send the samples to the SDR at the other end i receive GMSK waveforms with equal magnitiude aliases covering around 1 Mhaz bandwidth instead of 12.5 Khz as per AIS parameters used. i have used carrier frequency of 800025000 Hz in SDR. Screen shot is attached for any feedback please.

Thanks
